# Cordova 1.7.0 + childbrowser (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

Im getting this error.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova at file:///android_asset/www/childbrowser.js:87

I have done all of this:

To install the plugin, move www/childbrowser.js to your project's www folder and include a reference to it in your html file after phonegap.js.

Copy the image files folder www/childbrowser to your project's www folder. Note you need the entire folder not just the images.

Create a directory within your project called "src/com/phonegap/plugins/childBrowser" and move ChildBrowser.java into it.

In your res/xml/plugins.xml file add the following line:

Comment: Are you getting the "deviceready" event from Cordova? Did you make sure your HTML correctly references the cordoava-1.7.0.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem working in Eclipse off the demo from phonegap. They have use add this line in the "hello world":

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>`

But when you download the new phonegap it should be:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>`

Now it works for me :)

Comment: I have also faced same problem I have follow the tutorials form this site http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0 I have follow your solution but same problem occurs again. Do you have further idea about this.